# MySQL Query to Identify bad characters?

Tags: mysql

We have some tables that were set with the Latin character set instead of UTF-8 and it allowed bad characters to be entered into the tables, the usual culprit is people copy / pasting from Word or Outlook which copys those nasty hidden characters...

Is there any query we can use to identify these characters to clean them?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, which characters do you call "*bad characters*"?

Comment: Our Sales guys tend to copy / paste phone numbers alot and we get the following in the tables 803-644-0100 â

Comment: Or something like this >> 803-644-0100 â€Ž

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx Could you give us a bit more detail about your table structure? e.g. Is this a column that is dedicated to just phone numbers? An easy way of doing this ... `DESCRIBE "tablename";`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your connection chacater set was set to `UTF8` when you filled the data in.

`MySQL` replaces unconvertable characters with `?` (question marks):

```
SELECT  CONVERT('тест' USING latin1);

----
????
```

The problem is distinguishing legitimate question marks from illegitimate ones.

Usually, the question marks in the beginning of a word are a bad sign, so this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   myfield RLIKE '\\?[[:alnum:]]'
```

should give a good start.

Comment: Out character set was set to Latin by mistake.... Needless to say this table is huge and does have some bad data in it. If we switched the character set overnight to UTF8 for the table will it reindex and resolve the issue?

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx: no, it won't. The out-of-range values will not be magically converted back.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably noticing something like this ['bug'](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28263). The 'bad characters' are most likely UTF-8 control characters (eg \x80). You might be able to identify them using a query like

```
SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE LOCATE(UNHEX(80), bar)!=0
```

From that linked bug, they recommend using type `BLOB` to store text from windows files:

> Use BLOB (with additional encoding field) instead of TEXT if you need to store windows files (even text files). Better than 3-byte UTF-8 and multi-tier encoding overhead.

Take a look at [this Q/A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-convert-control-characters-in-mysql-from-latin1-to-utf-8) (it's all about your client encoding  aka `SET NAMES` )